# UIScrollView contentInset reset not working iOS8/9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I use the following when show/hide the keyboard:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrDetails.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrDetails.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    /* Set to NO so after the keyboard is hidden, the size goes back to normal */
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrDetails.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrDetails.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

But for some reason even though the size is set correctly when dismissing the keyboard

```
(lldb) po self.scrDetails.contentInset
 (top = 0, left = 0, bottom = 0, right = 0)
```

the effect is not shown on the device/simulator(the scrollbar remain at the previous keyboard up position)

See the image

[image]

I use autolayout, so I am not setting the contentSize directly.

Any suggestions what might help tracking this down?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party class TPKeyboardAvoiding. It manage keyboard.

Link : https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: thanks. I am aware of it, but in this case I want to fix this particular issue.